# comparison of two strings fails

Tags: objective-c, string, comparison

I make a comparison of two strings which are obviously identical. Unfortunately my if clause doesn´t work as expected:

```
NSLog(@"%@ == %@ ?",strippedString1,strippedString2);

if (strippedString1 == strippedString2) {
    [_newBuild setTextColor: [NSColor greenColor] ]; 
    [_OldBuild setTextColor: [NSColor greenColor] ]; 
}
```

This is my NSLog output: Build: 2A12-046 == Build: 2A12

Even a byte by byte comparison says both strings are identical:[image]

Any clues ?

Answer (score 3):

With `==` you are comparing pointer address, to compare the contents of the strings you could use:

```
 [strippedString1 isEqualToString: strippedString2];
```

Comment: Further to this you get constant folding in the compiler, so sometimes the `==` comparisons seem to magically work, and then sometimes fail depending on where the string is defined and what compiler settings you are using.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson: wow... so if I'm trying to check if 2 objects are the same (have the same address) I could end comparing their contents?

Comment: What I'm trying to say is : `const NSString s1 = @"hello"; ... NSString s2 = s1; ... if( s2 == @"hello" ) { ... }` may pass or fail depending on compiler settings. `==` will never compare the contents, only the location, but sometimes that location may be the same when you might not expect it.  I think the compiler only folds string / basic type constants, not general object constants, but I'm not sure if that is mandated or not - I'd certainly never rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

I think for String, you are supposed to use (This is Java) `.equals()` or equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare two NSStrings with the == operator, instead use

```
[strippedString1 isEqualToString:strippedString2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Important part: you meant to use [isEqualToString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/isEqualToString%3a)

Using == will check for equality of of the pointer, i.e. it will tell you if the two objects you are comparing are actually the same instance.

Instead I think you meant to check that the contents are the same, but accourding to the appledocs you will want to use isEqualToString when you know the two objects are strings as it is much faster than isEqual.